# NUXT - Route with dynamic path - multiple parameters

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a route path like the below

**path: '/board/:type(\d{2}):subtype(\d{2}):id(\d+)'**

so this is some thing like this

http://localhost:3000/board/112233333333

Here in the above case

**11** is dynamic value for **type**  ( max two digits )

**22** is dynamic value for **sub type** ( max two digits )

**33333333** is dynamic value for **id**.

Could any one please let me know how do I create a folder structure for this one ? If not possible what is the best idea to handle this case ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> As per the details in your question,

1. Your url is `http://localhost:3000/board/112233333333`
2. The last param in route must have totally 12 digits (any random 12 digits)

**112233333333 - 12 digits**

> We will work with below page structure to get to your final result

[image: we will work with this structure to get to your final result]

**Use** `validate()` in `_id.vue` to check if this route is a valid route.

1.`validate()` method has to return either true or false

```
export default {
    validate ({ params }) {
        return /^([0-9]{12,12})$/.test(params.id)
    }    
}
```

2.`params.id` in `validate()` method will hold the id *(value in url param)* , in your case it is `112233333333`

3.`/^([0-9]{12,12})$/.test(params.id)` will return `true` if id *(value in url param)* has 12 digits else return `false`

`true` - route will be loaded successfully

`false` - error page will be displayed *(404 page not found - because route was not recognized)*

**if true is returned by the validate method** then this means the page is allowed to be loaded. Now we have to make use of vuejs life cycle hooks to proceed further.

1.In the `created()` life cycle hook, extract the value from the url using `this.$route.params.id`

2.Split the value `this.$route.params.id` using regex. Use match method to group into the format you need. In your case you have split it into 2,2,8 digits. The regex in below snippet exactly does that

```
created(){

    var _id = this.$route.params.id;
    var regex = /^([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{8,8})$/;
    var contents = _id.match(regex);

    this.type = contents[1];
    this.subtype = contents[2];
    this.id = contents[3]; 
}
```

Now you have all the values you need after proper validation. Your can ignore the value in `contents[0]`.

Below is the code for testing the approach i have described here.

Place the code in `_id.vue` file and verify the results.

```
/* template code */
<template>
  <section>
    <h3>in board _id</h3>    
    <div>
        <div>type = {{type}}</div>
        <div>subtype = {{subtype}}</div>
        <div>id = {{id}}</div>
        <div>urlParam = {{$route.params}}</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

/* script */
<script>
export default {
    /* variables */
    data(){
        return{
            type : null,
            subtype : null,
            id : null
        }
    },
    /* route validation */
    validate ({ params }) {
        return /^([0-9]{12,12})$/.test(params.id)
    },
    /* extracting url params */
    created(){
        var _id = this.$route.params.id;
        var regex = /^([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{8,8})$/;
        var contents = _id.match(regex);
        this.type = contents[1];
        this.subtype = contents[2];
        this.id = contents[3]; 
    }
}
</script>
```

**Reference** https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-validate

Comment: Thanks for your answer .  Last value "33333333" length is not fixed . Sorry I didn't mention it in the question . It has dynamic length from size 1 to Max integer size . But you gave me idea for the implementation . Do you have any quick fix for the last one ?

Comment: try this regex /^([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{1})$/; -- this will expect the last match to have minimum length 1 and maximum is as you wish.

Comment: Thank You divine for the solution .

Comment: small correction , right regular expression is  /^([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{2,2})([0-9]{1,99})$/